# Insert space into UK postcode

Tags: php

With PHP 7.2, I am using the following code to insert a space into a UK postcode:

```
$postcode = "AB123CD";
echo wordwrap($postcode, strlen($postcode) - 3, " ", true);
```

The code above gives the correct result... "AB12 3CD".

However if the postcode is shorter, the code inserts 2 spaces instead of 1. So for example "A12BC" equals "A1 2B C" when it should be "A1 2BC".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please try removing the last parameter and verify the result

Comment: Given the complexities of the UK postcode system, you should not be surprised that a simple solution like this fails to work.

Comment: How do you know it shouldn't be `A12 BC` ? UK postcodes are fairly nonsensical (actually, that's true of the entire British address system), especially when you get to London (NW1) - short of implementing some kind of Postcode Anywhere or Experian EDQ type solution, you're going to have a bad time with this.

Comment: All postcodes follow the same format, where the last 3 characters is always a number followed by 2 letters. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom

Comment: @Reado - not in London they don't... but this is my *best guess* `preg_replace('/^([A-Z]{1,2}\d{1,2}) *(\d[A-Z]{2})?$/', "$1 $2", $p)`

Comment: Got an example?

Comment: @Reado ... actually, you might be right, I was sure there were some strange ones in London like Broadcasting House or Buck House that didn't have normally formatted postcodes - but I can't find any that I thought were now...

Answer (score 1):

This solution works better, with any size postcode:

```
$postcode = "AB123CD";
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{2})$/", " $1", $postcode); // AB12 3CD

$postcode = "A12BC";
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{2})$/", " $1", $postcode); // A1 2BC
```